# Add accessibility and validation to a search form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been given some feedback on some code.

The feedback: "no accessibility or validation has been considered for the search form"

Heres the code:

```
export const Search = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  return (
    <form className={styles.search} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type='text'
        id='search'
        name='search'
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={searchTerm || ''}
        placeholder='search'
      />
      <button className='btn' type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

After searching I cannot find anything else extra to add. I thought that forms and buttons have default accessibility.

I'm trying to learn how to add extra accessibility and validation to this form as I believe it is important to encourage use good accessibility practise. Any guidance would be great.

P.S the code is in React treat it like html and JavaScript if your'e unfamiliar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can identify this form as a search landmark for assistive technology with the use of role="search". Using the search landmark will help assistive technology to "read" the user that this is a search option and screen readers also have an option to navigate to this section directly instead of navigating through all the elements on the page.

[Search role landmark info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Search_role)

Secondly, all modern browsers support the input type="search", that works exactly as type="text" but helps with autocomplete option across domains, helping users with dyslexia not making mistakes when they need to use this option.

[Input type search info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search)

Third, like TJ answered, labels for user control elements like inputs are important for blind people. Screen readers "read" the values of these fields, if there is no label it can be confusing what should they fill there. You can use the  element with the for="someID" attribute, or you can use aria-label="labelText" attribute to add label for assistive technology. Although some of the screen readers will use the placeholder as the label when the value is empty, you can't use it as a label.

[Labeling controls info on W3C-WAI](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/)

Fourth, consider the validation, if it is not the default HTML5 validation, you need to let the user know about any errors so he can correct the mistakes. You can use an element like span with role="alert" or role="status" or use some tooltip open (just to cover more disabilities) to inform the user about errors and suggestions on how to correct them.

[Accessible form validation article on WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/formvalidation/)

In matter of form validation, you can use the HTML5 validation like TJ answered using the input attributes required/pattern/etc. or use your own business logic to validate the form in the handleSubmit function you write.

My code suggestion:

```js
export const Search = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  return (
    <form role='search' className={styles.search} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type='search'
        id='search'
        name='search'
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={searchTerm || ''}
        placeholder='search'
        aria-label='Enter your search term'
        required={true}
      />
      <span className='errMsg' role='status'>Error message here</span> {/*use CSS to show and hide msg*/}
      <button className='btn' type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Only accessibility issue I can notice is `placeholder='search'`. You should always use a `<label for="">`, placeholder is just a complimentary feature for normal people.

For validation you prob need `required` since it is the only `<input>`. You might also need `min`/`max`/`pattern` etc but that's up to you.

```
<label for="search">Search<label>
<input
    type='text'
    id='search'
    name='search'
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={searchTerm || ''}
    placeholder='search'
    required
  />
```